# Spark is replacing some rows with NULL while reading CSV as dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am using scala 2.11 and spark 2.4.
When I reading below csv

```
a,b,c,d,e
1,null,abc,1,true
null,baby,def,,false
value,none,nuLL,null,
some,name,nonull,9,false
0,,hello,8,false
```

I am getting this from dfWithNullEntries

```
+----+----+------+----+-----+
|   a|   b|     c|   d|    e|
+----+----+------+----+-----+
|   1|null|   abc|   1| true|
|null|baby|   def|null|false|
|null|null|  null|null| null|
|some|name|nonull|   9|false|
|   0|null| hello|   8|false|
+----+----+------+----+-----+
```

Look at third row it is totally incorrect displaying.
Actually I am trying to replace null values of different datatype columns.
Using below code snippet.

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("replace-null-with-empty-string").master("local[4]").getOrCreate()

val nullSchema = StructType(Array(
  StructField("a",StringType,true),
  StructField("b",StringType,true),
  StructField("c",StringType,true),
  StructField("d",IntegerType,true),
  StructField("e",BooleanType,true)
))

val dfWithNullEntries = spark.read
  .schema(nullSchema)
  .options(Map("header" -> "true"))
  .csv("D:\\codebase\\intellij\\sparkbyexamples\\src\\main\\resources\\nullentry.csv")

dfWithNullEntries.show()

/**
  * "" will replace null from string cols
  * 0 will replace null from integer cols
  * true will replace null from boolean cols
  */
val cleanDF = dfWithNullEntries
          .na.fill("",Array("a","b","c"))
          .na.fill(0)
          .na.fill(true)
cleanDF.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

While reading csv, spark will consider empty string as null. If you specify null in your csv, it will not be referred as nulltype it will be referred as normal string.

Now, you specified type of column 'd' as integer and one of the row value as null(which will be referred as string). Due to this data type mismatch you are getting whole row as null.

To solve this you  can use one option called as `nullValue` while reading csv.

```
option("nullValue", "null")
```

Comment: Thanks, is there any way to not convert anything to null value, i.e. always convert to empty string or 0 for number column?

Comment: I don't think there is such option. By default empty strings will be treated as null. well in a dirty way we can pass some random values to nullValue option (like, option("nullValue", "$$%%$$!%")) so that nothing will be treated as null value until and unless that random string mathes with any value in your CSV file. It's not a good idea though.

Comment: Looks like fillna() is the way, even though its another dataframe processing command.